# Filter items which array contains all of given values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a doc structure like this:

```
{
    "_index": "XXX",
    "_id": 0,
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_source": {
        "events" : [
            {"type": "A"},
            {"type": "B"},
            {"type": "C"}
        ]
    }

},
{
    "_index": "XXX",
    "_id": 1,
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_source": {
        "events" : [
            {"type": "A"},
            {"type": "C"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to try get the doc have "A" and "B", so in this case, just the first doc.
But I'm not sure how to do it.
I tried this, but this one give me all of doc (seems like this is searching for any docs that contains "A")

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "events",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {"term": {"events.type": "A"}},
              {"term": {"events.type": "B"}}
            ]
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this way, but this one give me none of docs

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "events",
        "query": {
            "match": {
                    "events.type": {
                        "query" : "A B",
                        "operator": "AND"
                }
                            
            }
        }
    }
},
```

The current one that is working for me is

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "events",
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "type": "A"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "events",
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "type": "B"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering that if there is an optimized way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple filters, but first of all `events` must be a nested field, so that all these filters are executed in a context of a single nested document (event).

Mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "events",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "A"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "B"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```